# How to use $nuxt.$loading from axios interceptor

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I would like to use `$nuxt.$loading` https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading/ outside of Vue component. I created central js for hitting APIs.

**services/api-client.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { state } from '../store/modules/sessions';

const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Api-Key': state().token
  }
});

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  // show nuxt loading here
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  // hide nuxt loading here
  if (response.data.status.code != 200) {
    throw { message: response.data.status.errorDetail };
  } else {
    return response;
  }

}, function (error) {
  // hide nuxt loading here
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default {
  all(path) {
    return axiosClient.get(path);
  },
  show(path) {
    return this.all(path);
  },
  create(path, params) {
    return axiosClient.post(path, params);
  },
  update(path, params) {
    return axiosClient.put(path, params);
  }
};
```

and from my **index.vue** I'm dispatching the actions which trigger the Api Request.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1> Welcome </h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default { 
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getInsiders', this);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your problem is this code below.
Please try this.

```
export default function({ $axios, store }: any) {
  $axios.onRequest((config: any) => {
    store._vm.$nextTick(() => {
      store._vm.$nuxt.$loading.start()
      return config
    })
  })

  $axios.onResponse((response: any) => {
    store._vm.$nextTick(() => {
      store._vm.$nuxt.$loading.finish()
      return response
    })
  })

  $axios.onError((error: any) => {
    store._vm.$nextTick(() => {
      store._vm.$nuxt.$loading.finish()
      return Promise.reject(error)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: For me this solved my problem. I spent hours reading official docs and no official solution worked. This works perfectly

Comment: Where to put? Inside plugins folder?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to declare own axios client?

Standard way how to do this is using nuxt's axios module and then customize it in your plugin.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios'],
plugins: ['~/plugins/axios']
```

**~/plugins/axios**

```
export default ({ $axios, redirect }) => {
  $axios.onError(error => {
    // do anything you need
  })
}
```

The axios module will manage loading status automatically.
Although you still can disable progress for individual requests

Eg from component/action

```
await this.$axios.$get('/myapi', { progress: false })
```